# Find equal substring in list of strings

Tags: c#, regex, linq, substring, contains

I'm trying to figure out, how to find equal sub-string in big list of strings.

This method works fine:

```
var results = myList.FindAll(delegate (string s) { return s.Contains(myString); });
```

But it also looks for sub-string with part of word, for example, if I'm looking for "you do" it founds also extra "you dont" because contains "you do.."

In case of string, this method seems gives desired result:

```
 bool b = str.Contains(myString);
 if (b)
 {
     int index = str.IndexOf(myString);    
 }
```

How to get same kind of matching with list

Comment: The easiest way might be to use regular expressions (e.g. `\byou do\b`)

Comment: @John Hello, I'm not sure about using of regular expression with looking for sub string in big list of strings, it must be for each string I guess

Comment: How big is the list?

Comment: @John about 50 000 strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to return all of the matches for a set of potential terms:

```
string[] stringsToTest = new [] { "you do", "what" };
var escapedStrings = stringsToTest.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)); // escape the test strings so that we can safely build them into the expression
var regex = new Regex("\\b(" + string.Join("|", escapedStrings) + ")\\b");
var matches = regex.Matches("How you do? How you don't? What you do? How you do what you do?");
```

If you only have one term you can rewrite this as:

```
var regex = new Regex(string.Format("\\b({0})\\b", Regex.Escape("you do")));
var matches = regex.Matches("How you do? How you don't? What you do? How you do what you do?");
```

And then you can match use `match.Groups[0]` (for each group in the match collection) to get the matched value:

```
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Matched {0} at {1}", m.Groups[0].Value, m.Groups[0].Index));
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/EKWN59228)

Comment: So, if my list  `List<string> myList = new List<string>();` contains about 50 000 strings like "How you do? How you don't? What you do? How you do what you do?", then in this case each string must be processed with `var matches = regex.Matches(myString)` in loop, right?

Comment: You sure, that is   not a hard processing for this case?

Comment: You will get better performance using `IndexOf` (not `Contains` as you're currently using), and then checking the next character after the matched string. It depends on how efficient you really need it to be. Test it. If it's too slow, optimize.

Comment: you mean  `IndexOf` with `delegate`?

Comment: I meant re the code you provided under _"In case of string, this method seems gives desired result:"_

Comment: Well, this method gives result for string, my goal process list, so same as with regex must be looped for each, works much slower

Comment: For the test string above, the regex method is at worst half the speed of non-regex method using `IndexOf` that produces similar results. Is this something you need to optimize (i.e. have you tested the speed of this to determine if it's too slow)? I'm sure someone else will happily give you an answer that uses `IndexOf`.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, until now I wasn't able to test your solution. I'm not sure, how to get strings list from regex matches and didn't found example in internet to check your solution. Could you give me some link or example, how this should be done

Comment: @Ai_ve what do you mean a list of strings? What strings?

Comment: I've added [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431975/convert-regex-matches-to-the-list-of-strings) with example of my code,  because it looks like a different kind of problem