# Convert regex matches to the list of strings

Tags: c#, regex, linq, substring, contains

I'm trying to find equal sub-string in big list about 50 000 strings, this way fine:

```
var results = myList.FindAll(delegate (string s) { return s.Contains(myString); });
```

but it also looks for sub-string with part of word, for example, if I'm looking for "you do" it founds also extra "you dont" because contains "you do..".

So, [this answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413996/find-equal-substring-in-list-of-strings) supposedly should work as i need, but I'm not sure, how to get strings list from regex matches for particular code:

```
foreach (string phrase in matchWordsList)
{
     foreach (string str in bigList)
     {
          string[] stringsToTest = new[] { phrase };
          var escapedStrings = stringsToTest.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)); 
          var regex = new Regex("\\b(" + string.Join("|", escapedStrings) + ")\\b");
          var matches = regex.Matches(str);

          foreach (string result in matches) /// Incorrect: System.InvalidCastException 
          {
              resultsList.Add(result);
          }
     }
}
```

Getting strings from `matches` directly to the `list` throws exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in test.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to type 'System.String'.

So, I'm trying to figure out, hot to convert  `var matches = regex.Matches(str);` to the list

Comment: What should the list contain?

Comment: @John `resultsList` must add result of `matches` from each string of `bigList` for each phrase by `matchWordsList`

Comment: This is wrong : foreach (string result in matches).  Matches returns a MatchCollection not a string.  I always tell people only use var when necessary.  You should of used : MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input, pattern);  Then the compiler would of found the error instead of getting a run-time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with linq. However you will need to `Cast` it first then `Select`

```
var resultsList = regex.Matches(str)
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Value)
                       .ToList();
```

or

```
someList.AddRange(
   regex.Matches(str)
         .Cast<Match>()
         .Select(m => m.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Match` type in `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (Match result in matches)
{
    resultsList.Add(result.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you were trying to do in your previous question.

Would this work? It combines your "matchWordsList" into a single expression, and then adds each match from `bigList` into `resultsList`:

```
var escapedStrings = matchWordsList.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)); 
var regex = new Regex("\\b(" + string.Join("|", escapedStrings) + ")\\b");
foreach (string str in bigList)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(str))
    {
        resultsList.Add(str);
    }
}
```

So if `matchWordsList` contains `["test","words","cheese"]`, and `str` is `"This is a test to check if Regex is matching words. I like cheese."`, it will add `str` to `resultsList` once (even though there are 3 matches).

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CQO56074)

Comment: Well, this looks like answer to my previous question, but in this topic I have to mark another one according to particular question. Can you edit your answer with this code in previous post to make me able to mark it as answer, please

Comment: I kind of think my answer to your previous question is correct. You wanted the _index_ of matches in your previous question. In this question, you just seem to want to record a list of strings that match one of the values in "matchWordsList", hence my different answer. Is that not correct?